# After delete trigger i have this error ,table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

i want to delete from table candidat after deleting from table cv but have this error :

```
DELETE FROM "CVTHEQUE"."CV" WHERE ROWID = 'AAAF9BAABAAALdxAAD' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3254129' and ( "IDCV" is null or "IDCV" is not null )
ORA-04091: table CVTHEQUE.CV is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CVTHEQUE.DELETEAFTERDELETECV", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CVTHEQUE.DELETEAFTERDELETECV'
```

CODE :

```
create table cv(
    idcv VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
    idformation VARCHAR2(20) References formations(idformation) on delete cascade,
    idspecialite VARCHAR2(20) References specialites(idspecialite) on delete cascade,
    idexperience VARCHAR2(20) References experiences(idexperience) on delete cascade,
    idcentreinteret VARCHAR2(20) References centreinterets(idcentreinteret) on delete cascade,
    idlangue VARCHAR2(20) References langues(idlangue) on delete cascade,
    idcandidat VARCHAR2(20) References candidats(idcandidat) on delete cascade
);

create or replace trigger deleteAfterdeleteCv
    after delete on cv
    for each row
begin
    delete from candidats where idcandidat = :old.idcandidat;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The mutation appears because, after the deletion of parent `candidats` record, all child `cv` records are deleted by cascade.

```sql
idcandidat VARCHAR2(20) References candidats(idcandidat) on delete cascade
```

Avoid mutating triggers.
Change the direction of records deletion. Perform deletion of `candidats` by `id` and all `cv` records will be deleted bycascade and trigger does not need at all.

Example of delete statement:

```sql
delete from candidats where idcandidat in (select idcandidat from cv where idcv = :value)
```